# How to apply patch in reverse?

Tags: magit, git-patch

How, if possible, to apply patch in reverse with Magit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use <kbd>v</kbd>. For more information see the [Applying](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Applying.html) section in the manual.

If you use the Evil package and more specifically `evil-magit`, then a different key, <kbd>-</kbd>, is bound to the revert command. `evil-magit`'s documentation contains [a table listing basic key bindings](https://github.com/justbur/evil-magit#key-bindings). It also shows what bindings differ between `evil-magit` and vanilla Magit.

Comment: When you want to apply a change in reverse, go to the respective diff in a Magit buffer, and then type `v`.